# Blazor UI Thread

Tags: c#, mvvm, blazor-server-side, winui-3

We're working on creating a library of View Models that can be used either in a Win UI 3 desktop app, or a Blazor web app.  The ViewModels generally implement INotifyPropertyChanged and frequently perform async operations that will then need to marshal the results back to the UI.  Because the library is used on different platforms, we're trying to avoid a dependency on the platform specific method of invoking code on the UI thread (i.e. DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue in WinUI / InvokeAsync in blazor) within the view models themselves.

Our current solution is to create an interface, then register application specific implementation with the dependency injection framework (Autofac in our case).

```
 public interface IUIThreadService
 {
     void ExecuteOnUIThread(Action action);
     Task ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(Action action);
 }
```

WinUI specific library implementation

```
public class UIThreadService : IUIThreadService
{
    private readonly DispatcherQueue _dispatcherQueue;

    public UIThreadService(DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue)
    {
        _dispatcherQueue = dispatcherQueue;
    }
    public void ExecuteOnUIThread(Action action)
    {
        _dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(action.Invoke);
    }

    public Task ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(Action action)
    {
        //CommunityToolkit extension
        return _dispatcherQueue.EnqueueAsync(action);
    }
}
```

Container bootstrap registration in Desktop App:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new();
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
    return new UIThreadService(App.CurrentWindow?.DispatcherQueue ?? 
                                   DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread());

})
.As<IUIThreadService>();
```

and then used like so in the View Model:

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IUIThreadService _uiThreadService;
    public SomeViewModel(IUIThreadService uiThreadService)
    {
       _uiThreadService = uiThreadService;
    }
   
   public async Task RunSomeAsyncOp()
   {
       var newValue = await SomeWebService.GetValue();
       _uiThreadService.ExecuteOnUIThread(() => SomeValue = newValue);

   }
   private string _val;
   public string SomeValue { get => _val; set => SetProperty(ref _val, value);}
   ... more code implementing INPC
}
```

I can understand how to invoke the action on the UI thread within a blazor component itself, however, is there a way to gain access to that method in the bootstrap (much like App.MainWindow in WinUI) in order to register that invocation with the DI container to be used in a service and or ViewModel in a generic way?

##EDIT per Simon's comment

Yes, we could as you suggest and wire the PropertyChangedEvent to StateHasChange().  But there could be other objects that might also need to be wired to UI thread such as properties of type ObservableCollection.  These would have their own INPC events which would also need to be wired up in the blazor component.

I could also create a class that implements the IUIThread interface in blazor and set a property on the ViewModel such as the example below.

```
public class BlazorUIThreadService : IUIThreadService
{
    private readonly Func<Action, Task> _invokeAsync;

    public UIThreadService(Func<Action, Task> invokeAsync)
    {
        _invokeAsync = invokeAsync;
    }
    public void ExecuteOnUIThread(Action action)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(Action action)
    {
        return _invokeAsync(action);
    }
}
```

Blazor Component

```
public class BlazorPage : ComponentBase
{
   private SomeViewModel _viewModel;
   
   [Inject]
   protected SomeViewModel ViewModel 
   { 
     get => _viewModel;
     set 
        {
           _viewModel = value;
           _viewModel.UiThreadService = new BlazorUIThreadService(base.InvokeAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to inject it using the DI framework and avoid having to 'remember' to set the property or use anything beyond an anonymous property with the InjectAttribute in the page component.

Is there something in the page rendering pipeline that could be used that supplies the InvokeAsync or StateHasChanged that could be injected into the ViewModel 'service' in the constructor as part of the rendering prior to assigning it to the final component?  Is there a better way?

Comment: IMHO Blazor doesn't have the same dispatcher abstractions as the XAML+databinding platforms, you'll anyway end up calling StateHasChanged, won't you? Why don't you just hook INotifyPropertyChanged from Blazor calling code (let null be ok for uiThreadService), I guess you can at least craft some nice reuseable methods (or generate code) for this (but it won't be "internal" like you want).

Comment: Looks like you're just trying to recreate SynchronizationContext, which I wouldn't do, because `await` already uses the current synchronization context, meaning you don't need to do any of this in most UI-based frameworks.  If you're using some framework that doesn't create a sychronization context to marshal code to the UI thread, then make one and set it as current in the UI thread and then "it just works".

Comment: Thank you @Servy, I think you're right.  I'm just struggling on how to do that.  For instance, we also use the IMessenger service in the CommunityToolkit which would send a message on a background thread.  How would the ViewModel receive that message and then get that back onto the UI thread for the update?

Comment: Your non-UI work should be methods that return tasks with any results that need to be displayed on the UI, the UI operations call and await those methods, and are then on the UI thread to use the results of those tasks in the UI thread.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean in concept.  But how do you handle things like subscribing to an external service like a Signalr service?  Or a timer thread that's doing work in the background on a different thread?  Wouldn't you have to get these things back onto the UI thread somehow?  I definitely feel like I have an architectural gap, that I'm coming at it with a bad design, but I'm not sure how to get it back on track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something in the page rendering pipeline that could be used that supplies the InvokeAsync or StateHasChanged that could be injected into the ViewModel 'service' in the constructor as part of the rendering prior to assigning it to the final component?

The `Renderer` is responsible for creating the `Dispatcher` but I am afraid there is no easy or elegant way of getting a reference to it before the component has been constructed.

You could possible solve it using reflection - Blazor registers an internal `Circuit` whose host has a reference to the `Renderer` - but implementing your `BlazorUIThreadService` using property injection is a much better solution for obvious reasons.

I am afraid there is no static property or similar available to get hold of the `Renderer` or the `Dispatcher` in Blazor.